# How do I use a sudo command to work in python

Tags: python

I am using ubuntu and I am trying to check if the password field is empty.

```
import subprocess

pass_max = subprocess.check_output({'"sudo'", "cat",  "/etc/shadow", "|", "awk", "{print}"])
```

After executing this code, i receive the error returned non-zero exit status 1. How do I resolve this issue? Is the error because of the sudo command?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried shlex?

```
import subprocess
import shlex

pass_max = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk '{print}'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not `sudo` but pipe operator `|` in the argument of check_output.

At least in my environment, the following works.

```
import subprocess as sp


with sp.Popen(["sudo", "cat", "6.py"], stdout=sp.PIPE) as p1:
    with sp.Popen(["grep", "with"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE) as p2:
        print(p2.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
print(p1.returncode)
print(p2.returncode)
```

output was

```
$ python 6.py
Password:
with sp.Popen([sudo, cat, 6.py], stdout=sp.PIPE) as p1:
    with sp.Popen([grep, with], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE) as p2:

0
0
```

(I saved my code as 6.py)